# Extract RSA Public key from x509 C#

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I am trying to extract the RSA public key PKCS#1 from X509Certificate base64. to generate 8 tag for zatca phase 2 but output of my code is incorrect any one can help me with it. what i'm missing here ?

I have used following code:-

```
string X509CertificateBase64 = "MIID6jCCA5CgAwIBAgITbwAAgbuRbo5tpQ+QjgABAACBuzAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjBjMRUwEwYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYFbG9jYWwxEzARBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgNnb3YxFzAVBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgdleHRnYXp0MRwwGgYDVQQDExNUU1pFSU5WT0lDRS1TdWJDQS0xMB4XDTIyMTEwOTA4MDcyMloXDTI0MTEwODA4MDcyMlowTjELMAkGA1UEBhMCU0ExEzARBgNVBAoTCjM5OTk5OTk5OTkxDDAKBgNVBAsTA1RTVDEcMBoGA1UEAxMTVFNULTM5OTk5OTk5OTkwMDAwMzBWMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAKA0IABGGDDKDmhWAITDv7LXqLX2cmr6+qddUkpcLCvWs5rC2O29W/hS4ajAK4Qdnahym6MaijX75Cg3j4aao7ouYXJ9GjggI5MIICNTCBmgYDVR0RBIGSMIGPpIGMMIGJMTswOQYDVQQEDDIxLVRTVHwyLVRTVHwzLTlmMDkyMjM4LTFkOTctNDcxOC1iNDQxLWNiYzMwMTMyMWIwYTEfMB0GCgmSJomT8ixkAQEMDzM5OTk5OTk5OTkwMDAwMzENMAsGA1UEDAwEMTEwMDEMMAoGA1UEGgwDVFNUMQwwCgYDVQQPDANUU1QwHQYDVR0OBBYEFDuWYlOzWpFN3no1WtyNktQdrA8JMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFHZgjPsGoKxnVzWdz5qspyuZNbUvME4GA1UdHwRHMEUwQ6BBoD+GPWh0dHA6Ly90c3RjcmwuemF0Y2EuZ292LnNhL0NlcnRFbnJvbGwvVFNaRUlOVk9JQ0UtU3ViQ0EtMS5jcmwwga0GCCsGAQUFBwEBBIGgMIGdMG4GCCsGAQUFBzABhmJodHRwOi8vdHN0Y3JsLnphdGNhLmdvdi5zYS9DZXJ0RW5yb2xsL1RTWkVpbnZvaWNlU0NBMS5leHRnYXp0Lmdvdi5sb2NhbF9UU1pFSU5WT0lDRS1TdWJDQS0xKDEpLmNydDArBggrBgEFBQcwAYYfaHR0cDovL3RzdGNybC56YXRjYS5nb3Yuc2Evb2NzcDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwIGCCsGAQUFBwMDMCcGCSsGAQQBgjcVCgQaMBgwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwIwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwMwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDSAAwRQIgeWUEjxXaW4s8XilH/abzbDJhHHjO3uLaD87YqioA89YCIQDNltfAU98b8FnTD7M8NYIk8cqi7OnPu7h85v5V1Bt3Hg==";
    
         public string ExtractFromX509Certificate(string certificateStr)
         {
             byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(certificateStr);
             var x509 = new X509Certificate2(data);
             
             return Convert.ToBase64String(x509.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData);
         }

public string Test1(){
   return   ExtractFromX509Certificate(X509CertificateBase64);

}
```

output="BGGDDKDmhWAITDv7LXqLX2cmr6+qddUkpcLCvWs5rC2O29W/hS4ajAK4Qdnahym6MaijX75Cg3j4aao7ouYXJ9E=";

but actual output should be = "MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEYYMMoOaFYAhMO/steotfZyavr6p11SSlwsK9azmsLY7b1b+FLhqMArhB2dqHKboxqKNfvkKDePhpqjui5hcn0Q==";

**I have updated my Question**
Currently using .net core 2.2

Comment: You cannot extract RSA public key when your certificate uses EC public key.

Comment: @Crypt32  how will i get the public in DER encoding?

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 hit end of support on December 23, 2019.  You _really_ ought to upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the certificate it can be seen that the key is an public EC key for secp256k1 (and not a public RSA key).

`x509.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData` returns the public key in *uncompressed* format: `0x04 + <32 bytes x coordinate> + <32 bytes y coordinate>`.

`MFYw...` specifies the public EC key in X.509/SPKI format. An export in this format is possible e.g. with `x509.GetECDsaPublicKey().ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`. This returns the key in DER encoding. If the DER encoding is Base64 encoded, the expected result `MFYw...` is returned.

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

...

string X509CertificateBase64 = "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";
byte[] x509CertificateRaw = Convert.FromBase64String(X509CertificateBase64);
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(x509CertificateRaw);

Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(x509Certificate.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData)); // 0461830CA0E68560084C3BFB2D7A8B5F6726AFAFAA75D524A5C2C2BD6B39AC2D8EDBD5BF852E1A8C02B841D9DA8729BA31A8A35FBE428378F869AA3BA2E61727D1
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(x509Certificate.GetECDsaPublicKey().ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo())); // MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEYYMMoOaFYAhMO/steotfZyavr6p11SSlwsK9azmsLY7b1b+FLhqMArhB2dqHKboxqKNfvkKDePhpqjui5hcn0Q==
```

---

**Edit:** Regarding your comment that you are using .NET Core 2.2:

In .NET Core 2.2 (as well as in .NET Framework) there is little or no support for the X.509/SPKI format. Here it is most convenient to use C#/BouncyCastle.
There are several ways to convert the public key to the X.509/SPKI format using C#/BouncyCastle. Since in your use case the public key is to be extracted from a certificate and the certificate already contains the public key in X.509/SPKI format (see [RFC 5280, 4.1. Basic Certificate Fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1)), it makes sense to export it *directly* with BouncyCastle's ASN.1 parser:

```cs
using System;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
...
string X509CertificateBase64 = "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";
byte[] x509CertificateRaw = Convert.FromBase64String(X509CertificateBase64);
Asn1InputStream asn1InputStream = new Asn1InputStream(x509CertificateRaw);
Asn1Sequence asn1SequenceRoot = Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(asn1InputStream.ReadObject());
Asn1Sequence asn1SequenceTbsCertificate = Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(asn1SequenceRoot[0]); // TBSCertificate
Asn1Sequence asn1SequenceSpki = Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(asn1SequenceTbsCertificate[6]); // SubjectPublicKeyInfo
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(asn1SequenceSpki.GetDerEncoded())); // MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEYYMMoOaFYAhMO/steotfZyavr6p11SSlwsK9azmsLY7b1b+FLhqMArhB2dqHKboxqKNfvkKDePhpqjui5hcn0Q==
```

Comment: ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo() does not contain .net core 2.2

Comment: @FaisalShahab - And how should we know that you are using .NET Core 2.2? The current version is .NET 7, if you are using such an old version, you should specify that in the question!

Comment: do you have any alternative?

Comment: @FaisalShahab - An alternative is BouncyCastle, see the *Edit* part of my answer.